# Push new Tab on Tabbed bar application

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tabbed bar application and I have the "Feed" tab as the initial view. I want a Button on the Feed view controller to push the map view controller & Tab.

[Tabbed Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kW1E.png)

Right now the button pushes the map fine, but the tabbed bar is still highlighting the "Feed" Section. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tab programmatically by doing the following:

```
_ = self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Where the index is the index of the tab you want to change to.

Comment: Thank You! -Note: I replaced the performSegue() with your code above and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Got it! Thank you